# PHP script free of syntax errors won't fully parse

Tags: php

I have been struggling with this PHP script on my personal web server for quite some time. No matter what I do, or what input I give the HTML form (this PHP script is the action page for that form), I end up with a page that looks like this:
[image]
[view larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA0Rw.png)

Below is my code, which is supposed to get a list of ids of the recipes with a tag matching the user's query, then display a quick overview of the matching recipes to the user, in table format:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <title>Recipe Database</title>
    <h1>recipe finder</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "xxxx";

    $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, "recipes");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $tag = $_POST["keyword"];

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM recipes WHERE tag1 LIKE '$tag'");
    $query2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM recipes WHERE tag2 LIKE 
   '$tag'");
    $query3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM recipes WHERE tag3 LIKE'$tag'");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $result2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
    $result3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3);
    $list = array_merge($result, $result2);
    $list = array_merge($list, $result3);

    if ($list[0] != ""){
    echo "<table>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
       echo "<tr>";
       $detailquery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE id LIKE 
    \"$list[$i]\"");
       $details = mysqli_fetch_array($detailquery);
       print "<h3>" . $details[1] . "</h3>";
       print "<p>" . $details[2] . " minutes</p>";
       print "<p>" . $details[3] . " servings</p>";
       echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

} else {
    echo "No recipe with that tag was found. Try a different tag.";
}
?>
```

I tested it on several different online syntax checkers and it came out clean. Yes, all other PHP scripts are running fine on my server. Yes, all the other PHP scripts are reading and writing to this database and others on my server without error. Yes, I did try wrapping body and html around the PHP script, it makes no difference. Yes, I have checked for unpaired quotation marks and apostrophes, there are none. Yes, I have tried storing the various queries in separate variables, that did not affect anything.

Any help would be appreciated, I am truly stuck on this one. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you don't have short tags turned on. Make sure you have <?php at  the top of your files instead of <?

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't believe I overlooked that. Now I only need to iron out the logical errors.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, it looks like I forgot to have the extended tag

```
<?php
```

instead of the short one without "php". My bad for being so oblivious.